# Django Deployment on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, django-deployment

I am going to seploy my first Django application to a cloud server like Amazon EC2 and the system is Linux Ubuntu.
But I cannot find a very good step-by-step tutorial for the deployment.

Could you recommend one?

And I also have the following questions:

1. What is the most recommended environment? Gunicorn, Apache+mod_python or ohters?
2. How to deploy my code? I am using mac and should I use ftp or check out from my github repository?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my stack:
Nignx + gunicon, Supervisor

Deployment, 
If you are planing frequent releases you should be looking at something like Fabric. Even of not frequent Fabric is a very good tool to be aware of.

People have preference in terms of stack, but this one has been working great for me.

Comment: Hi, Anup. Thank you. Do you have any tutorial on your stack? I will read up Fabric. May I know how does it ease the deployment?

Comment: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ this should serve as good starting point

Comment: Great! Thank you! Also, how can I upload my code to the host?

Comment: I usually maintain a resalable(working) branch of my code. and i clone on my remote host. this works. Be careful with DB migrations.